# Random Forest Feature Selection

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection, auc

Am seeing a precise scenario

I am running a random forest model with two independent variables(a,b) where both of them have significant variable importance according to `sklearn` (b:0.633, a:0.3666) and am getting an AUC of 0.86

However, when I am adding a third independent variable 'c' which I feel is very relevant, it shows feature importance as (a: 0.32, b:0.44, c:0.24) but now guess what
AUC is reduced to 0.81.... Isn't it like if a feature  of better importance getting added should improve AUC... Forgive me if am asking a stupid question

Comment: Please provide some details, code, data size etc. This could easily be a result of the data used being small, but you have provided few details to help with trouble shooting.

Comment: Data is 120,000 records...Y variable has two values 0,1... Number of 0s are 96.5% values and 1's 3.5% values... Highly imbalanced data set

Comment: Please revise your post. There is no way for anyone to provide meaningful advise